# Is it correct to say "tear the wrapper open by the side to take the straw out"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

There is a straw in a plastic wrapper as shown in the above picture.

There is a zigzag line on the side of the wrapper.

In order to take the straw out, we have to tear the zigzag line, not the top and bottom end of the wrapper because the id the purpose of the zigzag line for easy tearing.

Is it correct to say "**tear the wrapper open by the side to take the straw out**" or "**tear the side of the wrapper off to take the straw out**"?

Comment: Standard phrasing here is [*tear **along** dotted line,*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tear+along+dotted+line%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02CtlYbK6FVc2479afgqbZPTGtzbQ:1602511300392&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgvrvmm6_sAhUKAcAKHcK7CgoQpwUIIw&biw=1417&bih=685&dpr=1.32) so if your "zigzag" line isn't "dotted", perhaps ***tear along jagged line*** (or [***tear along perforation***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tear+along+perforation%22) if they've helpfully weakened the plastic sleeve at that point).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, "jagged line" seems correct, but you probably got one thing wrong, we don't tear longways, but sideways.

Comment: It's true that tearing sideways is more likely than tearing lengthwise, but for the specific usage I'm talking about (where there's some kind of "guide" showing where to tear), [it's always ***along***, never ***across***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tear+along+dotted+line%2Ctear+across+dotted+line&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctear%20along%20dotted%20line%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctear%20along%20dotted%20line%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tear the wrapper open by the side to take the straw out* is fine - I think *by* sounds a little unusual here (most people would probably say ***at** the side* or ***on** the side*, or maybe **from**) but it works just fine!

*Tear the side of the wrapper off to take the straw out* also works - your English is fine, but what you're describing might sound unusual to people. *Tear the side off* sounds like you're removing the side of the wrapper, but really you're starting a tear at the side, and then ripping it all the way across, right?

So what you're tearing **off** is the top part of the wrapper, but you're beginning at the side - that's where you first make a tear, so I think *tear the side of the wrapper to take the straw out* (no "off") sounds perfect!

Comment: I like the phrase "ripping it all the way across", which is exactly what I wanted to say

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the picture and see no zig-zag line. I do see a corrugated or ridged side. If that is where to open, I'd say

> Tear the ridged side to open.

Comment: I just want to say that *zigzag* is a good word to describe that shape, and *line* can be used to describe an edge or the shape it follows - it's just that it's figurative, so *edge* works better because it's the physical thing you're tearing. And it's common to have lines printed on things, especially to show where you need to tear them, so it might be confusing if people expect that but you're actually talking about something else! Just wanted to be clear about the nuance here.

Comment: This picture show the "zigzag border" and it looks like the picture above. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClWa2.png